# Confused with json filter inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code that need to compare 2 json arrays and create a new array. `data` is the main array that is used to compare, `nData` is 2nd json array where we are comparing the values. here is the criteria.

- If `nData`'s Id is equal to `data`'s `knowledge__c`, create a new key(named `icon`) and value as `bin`
- Else create a new key(named `icon`) and value as `non bin`.

Here is my code

```js
var data = [{
  "Id": "a8109000000CcktAAC",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000oq3ZAAQ",
  "ResearchState__c": "Not verified"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000Ccl4AAC",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000oiqdAAA",
  "ResearchState__c": "Not verified"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000Ccm1AAC",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000orsBAAQ",
  "ResearchState__c": "In verification"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000CcNFAA0",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000oipoAAA",
  "ResearchState__c": "Confirmed Partial Solution"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000CcNZAA0",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000onvHAAQ",
  "ResearchState__c": "Not verified"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000CcNPAA0",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000olFxAAI",
  "ResearchState__c": "In verification"
}];

var nData = [{
  "Id": "ka109000000ors1AAA"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oq3ZAAQ"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oiqdAAA"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oiqDAAQ"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oir9AAA"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oiqCAAQ"
}];

var articleList = [];
let myArticle = {};
for (let article of nData) {
  myArticle = article;
  var newA = data.filter((item) => {
    if (item.Knowledge__c == article.Id)
      myArticle.icon = 'Non bin';
    else
      myArticle.icon = 'bin';
  });

  articleList.push(myArticle);

}

console.log(articleList);
```

In my current code its adding `bin` to all the objects. i.e. `else` part is getting triggered.

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: are `data` and `ndata` gauranteed to be same length?

Comment: Those are arrays of objects, not JSON. `.filter()` is the wrong method to use, it's meant for, well, filtering out elements from an array. You need `.some()` or `.find()` instead.

Comment: no @richytong, they can vary. they are results of some search query in my system

Comment: @GuyIncognito what is the difference between `find()` and `some()`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive you have been looking for the `some` method and not the `filter`, like this:

```js
var data = [{
  "Id": "a8109000000CcktAAC",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000oq3ZAAQ",
  "ResearchState__c": "Not verified"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000Ccl4AAC",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000oiqdAAA",
  "ResearchState__c": "Not verified"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000Ccm1AAC",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000orsBAAQ",
  "ResearchState__c": "In verification"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000CcNFAA0",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000oipoAAA",
  "ResearchState__c": "Confirmed Partial Solution"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000CcNZAA0",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000onvHAAQ",
  "ResearchState__c": "Not verified"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000CcNPAA0",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000olFxAAI",
  "ResearchState__c": "In verification"
}];

var nData = [{
  "Id": "ka109000000ors1AAA"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oq3ZAAQ"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oiqdAAA"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oiqDAAQ"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oir9AAA"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oiqCAAQ"
}];

var articleList = [];
let myArticle = {};
for (let article of nData) {
  myArticle = article;
  if(data.some((item) => item.Knowledge__c == article.Id)){
      myArticle.icon = 'Non bin';
   } else{
      myArticle.icon = 'bin';
  }

  articleList.push(myArticle);

}

console.log(articleList);
```

With the `some` method I check if there is `Knowledge__c` in the `data` array with an `Id` from `nData`'s objects

Comment: Hi @Ran Marciano. Sorry for my ignorance, what is difference between `some` and `find`?

Comment: @user3872094 `find` returns the value of the first element in an array that satisfies function condition, while `some` returns boolean value by checking if any element satisfies condition.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
  {
    Id: 'a8109000000CcktAAC',
    DiagBinder__c: 'a8009000000boTeAAI',
    Knowledge__c: 'ka109000000oq3ZAAQ',
    ResearchState__c: 'Not verified'
  },
  {
    Id: 'a8109000000Ccl4AAC',
    DiagBinder__c: 'a8009000000boTeAAI',
    Knowledge__c: 'ka109000000oiqdAAA',
    ResearchState__c: 'Not verified'
  },
  {
    Id: 'a8109000000Ccm1AAC',
    DiagBinder__c: 'a8009000000boTeAAI',
    Knowledge__c: 'ka109000000orsBAAQ',
    ResearchState__c: 'In verification'
  },
  {
    Id: 'a8109000000CcNFAA0',
    DiagBinder__c: 'a8009000000boTeAAI',
    Knowledge__c: 'ka109000000oipoAAA',
    ResearchState__c: 'Confirmed Partial Solution'
  },
  {
    Id: 'a8109000000CcNZAA0',
    DiagBinder__c: 'a8009000000boTeAAI',
    Knowledge__c: 'ka109000000onvHAAQ',
    ResearchState__c: 'Not verified'
  },
  {
    Id: 'a8109000000CcNPAA0',
    DiagBinder__c: 'a8009000000boTeAAI',
    Knowledge__c: 'ka109000000olFxAAI',
    ResearchState__c: 'In verification'
  }
];

var nData = [
  {
    Id: 'ka109000000ors1AAA'
  },
  {
    Id: 'ka109000000oq3ZAAQ'
  },
  {
    Id: 'ka109000000oiqdAAA'
  },
  {
    Id: 'ka109000000oiqDAAQ'
  },
  {
    Id: 'ka109000000oir9AAA'
  },
  {
    Id: 'ka109000000oiqCAAQ'
  }
];

const articleList = nData.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  icon: data.some((dt) => dt.Knowledge__c === item.Id) ? 'bin' : 'non bin'
}));

console.log(articleList);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [{
  "Id": "a8109000000CcktAAC",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000oq3ZAAQ",
  "ResearchState__c": "Not verified"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000Ccl4AAC",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000oiqdAAA",
  "ResearchState__c": "Not verified"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000Ccm1AAC",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000orsBAAQ",
  "ResearchState__c": "In verification"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000CcNFAA0",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000oipoAAA",
  "ResearchState__c": "Confirmed Partial Solution"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000CcNZAA0",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000onvHAAQ",
  "ResearchState__c": "Not verified"
}, {
  "Id": "a8109000000CcNPAA0",
  "DiagBinder__c": "a8009000000boTeAAI",
  "Knowledge__c": "ka109000000olFxAAI",
  "ResearchState__c": "In verification"
}];

var nData = [{
  "Id": "ka109000000ors1AAA"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oq3ZAAQ"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oiqdAAA"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oiqDAAQ"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oir9AAA"
}, {
  "Id": "ka109000000oiqCAAQ"
}];

const articleList = nData.map(article => data.find(item => item.Knowledge__c == article.Id) ? { ...article, icon: 'Non bin' } : { ...article, icon: 'bin'});

console.log(articleList);
```